# Prove or disprove $\bar{A}*\overline{(B \cup C)} = \overline{(A*(B \cup C))}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to learn Discrete mathematics by myself, from a well known book by Kenneth H. Rosen. 
I have tried to solve this problem, but, after evaluating the left side, I get stuck how to proceed with right hand side,
Here is how, I solved $\text{LHS}$ as follows:
 (Note : symbol $*$ is for cartesian product of sets)

---

> $\text{let (a,x) }\epsilon \text{ } \bar{A}*\overline{(B\cup C)}$
>
> $\Rightarrow \{(a,x)\text{ }|\text{ }x\text{ }\epsilon\ \overline{(B \cup C)} \}$
>
> $\Rightarrow \{(a,x)\text{ }|\text{ }x\text{ }\epsilon\ {(\bar{B} \cap \bar{C})} \}$
>
> $\Rightarrow \{(a,x)\text{ }|\text{ }x\text{ } \epsilon \bar{B} \wedge x\text{ }\epsilon\bar{C} \}$

I don't know if it's correct or not.

I solved $\text{LHS}$ using above approach, but I am not able to think of a starting point for solving the $\text{RHS}$, any suggestion or hint will help a lot.

P.S: I have just started learning discrete mathematics, so, please don't judge on asking for a naive question.

Comment: I don't know, why cancel is showing error, I tried to make it as readable as I can.

Comment: Use \in and \notin for those symbols.

Comment: What are the cancel symbols supposed to be?

Comment: Try doing an actual example. It'll get you unstuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BIG HINT

Let the universal set be $\{0,1\}$ with $A=B=C=\{0\}$.

Then LHS=$\{(1,1)\}$. What is the RHS?

Comment: As $A = B = C = \{0\}$ and the universal set is $U = \{0,1\}$, Let, $B \cup C$ be $T$, then $\bar{A}*\overline{B \cup C} = \bar{A}*\bar{T}$ and $\overline{(A * (B\cup C))} = \overline{(A*T)}$. We can also conclude that, $A*B or B*C or A*C\subseteq U*U$, where $U*U$ is $\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$, and solving it results that, $RHS$ should be $\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)\}$. This is my reasoning for your example, Is it correct?

Comment: The RHS= complement of (0,0) i.e. $\{(1,1),(0,1),(1,0)\}$

Comment: It means, I was correct with your example, Thank you @S. Dolan, for your help.